# NameError in ReportsController#show uninitialized constant Report Rails.root: /vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am currently trying to get the current my page to render a template with rails show.html.haml but I get this uninitialized constant error. I generated the controller however I didn't generate the scaffold because I don't want to use a model to generate the page. Below is the error

```
NameError in ReportsController#show uninitialized constant Report  Rails.root: /vagrant
```

I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong, but I think it has something to do with the Routes or something I didn't create that rails expects. I am getting an uninitialized constant Report. I think I need to define the resource but that didn't seem to work so I might not have done that properly so it is excluded in my route file below. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my route file

```
# Route prefixes use a single letter to allow for vanity urls of two or more characters
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  if defined? Sidekiq
    require 'sidekiq/web'
    authenticate :user, lambda {|u| u.is_admin? } do
      mount Sidekiq::Web, at: '/admin/sidekiq/jobs', as: :sidekiq
    end
  end

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin' if defined? RailsAdmin

  # Static pages
  match '/error' => 'pages#error', via: [:get, :post], as: 'error_page'
  get '/terms' => 'pages#terms', as: 'terms'
  get '/privacy' => 'pages#privacy', as: 'privacy'

  # OAuth
  oauth_prefix = Rails.application.config.auth.omniauth.path_prefix
  get "#{oauth_prefix}/:provider/callback" => 'users/oauth#create'
  get "#{oauth_prefix}/failure" => 'users/oauth#failure'
  get "#{oauth_prefix}/:provider" => 'users/oauth#passthru', as: 'provider_auth'
  get oauth_prefix => redirect("#{oauth_prefix}/login")

  # Devise
  devise_prefix = Rails.application.config.auth.devise.path_prefix
  devise_for :users, path: devise_prefix,
    controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions',
      passwords: 'users/passwords', confirmations: 'users/confirmations', unlocks: 'users/unlocks'},
    path_names: {sign_up: 'signup', sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', home: 'home'}
  devise_scope :user do
    get "#{devise_prefix}/after" => 'users/registrations#after_auth', as: 'user_root'
  end
  get devise_prefix => redirect('/a/signup')

  # User
  resources :users, path: 'u', only: :show do
    resources :authentications, path: 'accounts'
  end
  get '/home' => 'users#show', as: 'user_home'

  get '/reports' => 'reports#show'

  # Dummy preview pages for testing.
  get '/p/test' => 'pages#test', as: 'test'
  get '/p/email' => 'pages#email' if ENV['ALLOW_EMAIL_PREVIEW'].present?

  get 'robots.:format' => 'robots#index'

  root 'pages#home'
end
```

controllers/report_controller

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    render template: "reports/show"
  end
end
```

views/reports/show.html.haml

```
%h1
  hello world!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    render template: "reports/show"
  end
end
```

should have been

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user

  def show
    render template: "reports/show"
  end
end
```